# How to display message at the bottom of a display file in CL program?

Tags: message, ibm-midrange

Suppose a display file has been declared in a CL program. It accepts some user input and conducts some validations to it. If it fails the validation a message would be displayed on the bottom of the display file. Is it possible to achieve this in CL? I have tried SNDPGMMSG with MSGTYPE(*DIAG), but the message is displayed only after the program has been terminated, and not on the display file during the execution.

The message to be sent is retrieved from message file so using field to display message is not applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally we use message subfile to achive what you required above.
It can be done in display file for both CL and RPG

For CL example, you could read here http://www.mcpressonline.com/cl/the-cl-corner-letting-the-user-know-what-s-right-and-wrong.html.
You could search for "cl program message subfile" for other examples

Comment: Is it possible without message subfile?

Comment: If without message subfile, i use method suggested by @Buck Calabro with RTVMSG to retreive message description from message file.

Comment: So SNDPGMMSG cannot make message displayed in display file without message subfile then?

Comment: I think can. You need to experiment with SNDPGMMSG keyword in CL (press F4) . Then retrieved back using RCVMSG. Sorry,I don't have a running,tested example.

Comment: SNDPGMMSG with TOPGMQ(*EXT), MSGTYPE(*STATUS) and message subfile works fine, I have tried that. Any other combinations of option parameter of SNDPGMMSG I have tried so far for case without subfile have all failed. Is there anything else I have got wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Define a 75 character field in your display file DDS.  Call it MESSAGE.  In your CL do something like:

```
if (&option *ge '35') do
  CHGVAR &MESSAGE 'Invalid option chosen'
  goto getOption
enddo
```

Comment: Well, I need to retrieve the message to be sent from a message file so this one is not very suitable.

Comment: The description of the problem does not include a message file requirement.  The answer by @lamLam is the one that experienced midrange programmers use.